# Некорректный вывод значений для функции с изменяемым чслом параметров

Tags: c

Проблема в том, что, по сути, функция должна вывести значения, переданные ей, но она печатает что-то совершенно другое, хотя, если увеличивать `p` на два, то все работает корректно.
Не понимаю, почему так происходит.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printReceivedElements(int count, ...){
    int * p = &count; int i;
    for(i = 0;i < count; ++i){
        printf(" %d ", *(p++));
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printReceivedElements(6, 1, 13, 34, 23, 1, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что параметры будут идти в памяти по порядку? Используйте макросы из `<stdarg.h>`.

Comment: "по сути, функция должна вывести..." - это на основании чего вы тут увидели такую "суть"?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так нужно:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void printReceivedElements(int count, ...) {
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap,count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        printf(" %d ", va_arg(ap,int));
    }
    va_end(ap);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printReceivedElements(6, 1, 13, 34, 23, 1, 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `va_end` забыли :-P

Comment: @Ainar-G Спасибо, поправился.

Answer (score 0):

Доступ к переменным параметрам функций осуществляется через средства, предоставляемые стандартной библиотекой в заголовке `<stdarg.h>`, т.е. `va_list`, макросы `va_start`, `va_arg` и т.п.

То, что вы пытаетесь делать в своем коде не имеет к этому никакого отношения. Откуда у вас даже взялась такая странная идея? Что это за адресная арифметика и к чему она тут?

Comment: нам преподаватель схожее показал на паре:)

Comment: Может, я шото неправильно тут сделал, но он приводил примери без использования вишеперечисленних вами функций, средствами передачи количества аргументов.

Comment: @user11729819: То, что делал ваш преподаватель - полнейшая бессмысленнейшая чушь. Тут уже вроде проводили расследование на тему того, откуда это идет. Львов?

Comment: Вов, да , я со Львова, Политехнический институт:)

Comment: А что, кто-то со Львова уже задавал такой вопрос:)?